# Is the latency in Jetty Access Logs measured in milliseconds by default?

Tags: logging, jetty, access-log

I'm pretty new to Jetty and have a new web service to maintain. The access logs appear to use the default configuration and have lines like like the following one.

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [19/Dec/2016:21:35:20 +0000] "GET /v1/customers/cust@omer.com/status HTTP/1.1" 200 65 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36" 3
```

I found a [nice little article on the Jetty request log (i.e. access log) format](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-jetty-request-logs.html). Unfortunately, the article doesn't state whether or not latency (the number at the end of the line - in this case `3`) is measured in milliseconds by default. I found [a blog article which states that latency is measured in ms by default](https://dsharpdotnet.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/monitoring-latency-in-jettys-request-log/) but I thought that I would post this question in attempt to vet this fact.

So, does the default configuration of Jetty access logs measure latency in milliseconds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, log latency is measured in [milliseconds](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/AbstractNCSARequestLog.java#L204).

I will see what I can do about getting the doco updated.
Edit: I've put in a PR to have it changed.